# Angular Interceptor and Browser Login Dialog

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

When I return 401 to the client Chrome opens Credentials Dialog right away before I get into Interceptor's responseError handler. How does it work with a custom Login form? Can I suppress Browser login prompt? Here is my Interceptor:

```
.service('APIInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope, $location) {
var service = this;

service.request = function(config) { 
        access_token = currentUser ? currentUser.access_token : null;

    if (access_token) {
        config.headers.authorization = access_token;
    }
    return config;
};
service.responseError = function (rejection) {
    if (rejection.status === 401) {
        $location.path('/login');
    }
    return rejection;
};
})
```

And this is my C# test code:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(
Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Test Error Message"));
```

Thanks

Comment: The dialog appears, AFAIK, due to `WWW-Authenticate: Basic` headers in the response. Do you have control of your server? If so, you could change the headers. I don't think there is any other way with JS, because the browser reacts to the request before JS